# Как вывести массив, возвращённый ajax-ом

Tags: jquery, php

Есть функция на ajax, возвращающая html-код комментариев. Из обработчика запроса нужно вернуть не только комментарии, но и ещё одну переменную. Возвращаю массив. Массив приходит успешно. Но как же его потом отобразить. Вот пример работы данной операции.(естественно не рабочий). Поправьте его, пожалуйста.

jQuery:

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: comments.php,
    type: "post",
    data: // ... не важно какие
    success: function(response){
        /* нерабочая часть */
        $('#comments').append(response[0]); // сюда выводим первый элемент массива
        $('#list').text(response[1]); // сюда выводим соответственно 2-ой элемент
        /* конец не рабочей части */
    });
});
...
```

comments.php:

```
...

    $com = '...'; // содержит html-код комментариев
    $perem = 20; // содержит их колличество
    echo array($com, $perem);

...
```

Comment: JSON в помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: comments.php,
    type: "post",
    data: {some_key: some_val},
    success: function(response){
        $('#comments').append(response[0]); // сюда выводим первый элемент массива
        $('#list').text(response[1]); // сюда выводим соответственно 2-ой элемент
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

**PHP**

```
// ...
$com = '...'; // содержит html-код комментариев
$perem = 20; // содержит их колличество
echo json_encode(array($com, $perem));
exit();
```

Comment: А зачем в конце exit()???

Comment: Контролька. Бывают случаи, когда может выполнится следующий скрипт. Это больше защита от "дурака", чем руководство к действию.

Comment: Эм, следующий скрипт где?

>url: comments.php, // вызывается один скрипт

В самом php тоже пара строк.

Comment: > В самом php тоже пара строк.

Если это так, то да. А если нет?

Comment: Ну если нет то всегда есть Условия на выполнение, лишний раз ставить кик на завершение тоже не айс.

Просто стало интересно, никогда не занимался подобным :) чтобы ставить exit() в ajax скрипт

Comment: я часто ставлю <blockquote>exit();</blockquote> в  ajax скриптах...

Comment: Интересно что-то получается. Данные возвращаются в виде 

<li>... содержимое комментария ...</li>["",8] // Куда-то за пределы массива вылез 1-ый элемент массива

И в ajax-е  срабатывает
error: function(){
    ...
}, хотя firebag показывает нормально отработанные комменты(html-структуру)